# Is this weird response from my Application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have made an application that converts list of URLs to it's new redirected URLs list by server. But i have seen some weird  response from my application.

It's only able to convert Max 2 URLs only if redirected URLs's domain name is same. i.e if i have list of URLs then it starts conversion but it can not convert URL's if there are more than 2 redirected URL's of same domain name otherwise its working fine.  So if more than 2 redirected URLs that have same domain name process can not be proceed.

Why this is happening?

My code is :

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
WebResponse myWebResponse = request.GetResponse();
absoluteUri = request.GetResponse().ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri;
```

I need help.

Comment: HTTP request limit = 2. So it is just how it works. I believe you can alter this in the registry.

Comment: Can you explain with detail i can't get this. Thanks.

Comment: Mmmm, no. I have given you enough information to research this further.

Answer (score 0):

As being said default connection limit to the same host is 2, but you can change it adding following code to your `App.config` file:

```
 <configuration> 
  <system.net> 
    <connectionManagement> 
      <add address="*" maxconnection="100" /> 
    </connectionManagement> 
  </system.net> 
</configuration>
```